# What is the difference between "excitement" and "excitation"?

Tags: morphology

I know that the first one is usually used for describing emotional state and the second one in science e.g. in physics.

But why are these words different and what is the logic behind each of these forms?

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://the-difference-between.com/excitation/excitement

Comment: @Keepthesemind I've read this but it doesn't explain how each of these words was derived from "excite" verb and why they are different.

Comment: @a-rodin: Why are any two words "different"? *Because we need different words to refer to different things*. Your two can be (and often *have been*) used interchangeably, but over time we come to associate each more strongly with one specific context. The more people do this, the more pronounced the distinction becomes. Same as ***electric, electrical***, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it seems the suffix *-ment* describes a state, a result if you want, whereas *-ation* seems to indicate an *action*.

From the [source](http://the-difference-between.com/excitation/excitement) that @Keep these mind mentioned, we see indeed for excitement:

> the state of being excited

and for excitation:

> The act of exciting [...]
>   The act of producing excitement [...]
>   (physiology) The activity produced in an organ [...]
>   (physics) The change in state [...]

Indicating *action* rather than a state.

Comment: Good vibrations...